# Unable to sign module (vboxdrv)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, signing, ubuntu-16.04

Since I have secure boot on Ubuntu 16.04 enabled, I need to sign vboxdrv.

I create signing keys using:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Descriptive name/"
```

Then I sign the module:

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vboxdrv)
```

However, when I call:

modinfo vboxdrv

The module is not confirmed to be signed:

`$ modinfo vboxdrv
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
version:        5.0.18_Ubuntu (0x00240000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     316C2AE8082B5DFBAABE7EA
depends:

vermagic:       4.4.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)`

I then run:

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

And reboot, which prompts me to import a machine owner key.

However, this fails (invalid parameter (2)).

I think its due to the module not being signed earlier, as running modinfo vboxdrv should confirm that the module was signed.

Comment: I filed a bug against `mokutil` here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mokutil/+bug/1600452 and against `shim` here https://github.com/rhinstaller/shim/issues/55

Comment: This has been patched already by a shim developer (I tested it and it works).  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030662/cant-install-virtualbox-in-arch/59536730#59536730) answer I posted can help to solve it

Answer (score 3):

This is due to Lenovo firmware not supporting EFI_VARIABLE_APPEND_WRITE.  One of the shim developers has already rewritten MokManager.efi to work on affected Lenovo machines although it's unclear how long it will take this to be merged and pulled downstream by Ubuntu.  You can follow the issue on shim's github issue tracker [here](https://github.com/rhinstaller/shim/issues/55).

If you can't wait (guilty as charged), you can compile shim and test it yourself.

If you don't have `git`, `gnu-efi`, `libnss3-tools` and `pesign` you'll need to install them first (more info on setting up an EFI development environment can be found [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/prepare.html), I'm using a fairly new installation of Ubuntu 16.04, but it's possible that I've installed required other libraries/tools and forgotten about them--just look for errors when compiling and install any missing packages as neccesary):

```
sudo apt-get install git gnu-efi libnss3-tools pesign
```

Next, clone the branch of the git repository with the patch:

```
cd /src
git clone -b fix-lenovo-write https://github.com/lcp/shim.git
cd shim
```

Next you'll need to modify the Makefile (shim developers aren't using Ubuntu)

```
gedit Makefile
```

Make the following changes (credit to this [post](https://github.com/rhinstaller/shim/issues/55#issuecomment-235907007http://)):

```
-OBJCOPY_GTE224  = $(shell expr `$(OBJCOPY) --version |grep ^"GNU objcopy" | sed 's/^.version //g' | cut -f1-2 -d.` \>= 2.24)
+#OBJCOPY_GTE224  = $(shell expr `$(OBJCOPY) --version |grep ^"GNU objcopy" | sed 's/^.version //g' | cut -f1-2 -d.` \>= 2.24)
+OBJCOPY_GTE224  = 1

-LIB_PATH       = /usr/lib64
+LIB_PATH       = /usr/lib

-EFI_PATH       := /usr/lib64/gnuefi
+EFI_PATH       := /usr/lib
```

Next you'll need to comment out an unused variable in shim.c:

```
gedit shim.c
```

Make the following change at line 1118:

```
@@ -1118,7 +1118,7 @@ static EFI_STATUS handle_image (void *data, unsigned int datasize,
        EFI_STATUS efi_status;
        char *buffer;
        int i;
-       unsigned int size;
+       //unsigned int size;
        EFI_IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *Section;
        char *base, *end;
        PE_COFF_LOADER_IMAGE_CONTEXT context;
```

Compile shim:

```
make
```

Turn off secure boot temporarily:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Set your password, reboot, and follow the instructions to disable secure boot (password is tricky, it asks you to enter certain characters from the password rather than the whole thing).

Backup MokManager.efi and double check that it is backed up:

```
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi.bak
sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
```

Move your patched version of MokManager to the EFI partition.

```
sudo mv ./MokManager.efi.signed /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
```

Enroll your key (modify as necessary depending on where you key is and what it's named):

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

Set password, reboot and follow instructions to enroll MOK.  It should succeed on Lenovo machines now.

Revert to the original version of MokManager and renable secure-boot:

```
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi ./MokManager.efi.signed
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi.bak /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
sudo mokutil --enable-validation
```

Set password, reboot, follow instructions.

Sign your modules, load them with modprobe and enjoy!

**Note:** hopefully this will be officially patched in most distribution's repos fairly soon.  This answer is an option for exceptionally impatient people who are comfortable building the patch from source and testing it.  It worked on my machine (Lenovo P50) but that doesn't mean that it will work for everyone.  If you aren't comfortable with building efi applications from source just wait for the patched version to hit the repos (at which point I'll update this answer).

Comment: Does this PPA fix? https://launchpad.net/~cyphermox/+archive/ubuntu/efi